# Copy files from Source to Destination if they don't already exist

Tags: robocopy, xcopy

I use robocopy to copy SQL Server Transaction Log files from Primary server to Standby server (due to a specific reason I don't use SQL log shipping job to copy). SQL Server generates a new file every 15 minutes.

This is the batch file that contains robocopy with flags:

```
@echo off
robocopy \\PrimaryPath\SourceDB\ C:\StandbyPath\DataWarehouse\Replica\ /XC /XN /XO
```

The primary server keeps transaction log files for 5 days, I want to copy new files only but not sure why robocopy keeps copying old files although I use /XC /XN /XO.

I have tried to use xcopy like this but the problem is same as robocopy

```
xcopy \\PrimaryPath\SourceDB\*.trn C:\StandbyPath\DataWarehouse\Replica\ /c /d /y /k
```

Please guys help me out this issue.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Peter

Comment: You don't need the parameters `/XC /XN /XO` in your case. Robocopy does not copy identical files again by default. Please share the log of robocopy, if your problem still exists.

Comment: Hi @Thomas, thank you for your instructions, I have changed command without parameters as your suggestions but the problem still exists. It means the robocopy keeps copying the old files despite they already exist in the destination folder. The log file was generated, could you please let me know what is the best way to share the robocopy log file. I have googled but no help

Comment: Create a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) first. Before executing robocopy, confirm that an exact copy of your file exists on your server and on your backup server by computing a checksum ([`Get-FileHash`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash)) and by comparing the timestamps with ([`Get-Item`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item)). Then do your robocopy operation and show us the log (as code formatted text in your Q), where it copies the file.